# JDBC Error when moving JAR from $HOME/jre/lib/ext to Gradle

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, gradle, java-8

My team has our application's com.mysql.jdbc.Driver jar in the $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext/ folder, but i'm trying to remove this dependency on the JDK to create a more repeatable build with Gradle.

I added the driver into my build.gradle, which you can see at the top of my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
        compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.+'
        compile group: 'com.notnoop.apns', name: 'apns', version: '1.0.0.Beta6'
        compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.21'
        compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '1.7.2'
        compile group: 'net.sf.jazzy', name: 'jazzy', version: '0.5.2-rtext-1.4.1'
        compile group: 'org.apache.lucene', name: 'com.springsource.org.apache.lucene.search.spell', version: '2.4.1'
        compile group: 'com.rabbitmq', name: 'com.springsource.com.rabbitmq.client', version: '1.8.1'
        compile group: 'com.sun.xml', name: 'com.springsource.com.sun.xml.bind', version: '2.2.0'
        compile group: 'com.sun.xml.rpc', name: 'jaxrpc-impl', version: '1.1.3_01'
        compile group: 'com.rabbitmq', name: 'amqp-client', version: '3.6.5'
        testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
        compile group: 'com.mashape.unirest', name: 'unirest-java', version: '1.3.1'
        compile fileTree(dir: 'local_lib', include: '*.jar')
}
```

After removing the jar from $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext/ and putting it in gradle, I get this error in the Catalina logs after trying to access the database:

```
database.BaseDbao.getConnection - We could not create any connection.
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1136)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
    at database.BaseDbao.getConnection(BaseDbao.java:116)
    at database.UserDbao.getAuthorizedResultBean(UserDbao.java:357)
    at database.Dbao.getAuthorizedResultBean(Dbao.java:3635)
    at AuthServlet.doPost(AuthServlet.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at servlets.filters.servletContextFilter.doFilter(servletContextFilter.java:11)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1130)
    ... 22 more
Dbao.getAuthorizationResultBean() Error - Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
LoginFailed for :suburbantest:because ::10.0.0.22
```

Any insight would be highly appreciated!

Comment: If i put the JAR in the Tomcat/lib folder it works. this of course has the same issue as putting the JAR in the ext folder, because it makes the web app dependent on a specific Tomcat JAR. Why does it seem to work everywhere except in Gradle?

Comment: Are you sure that it is the jdbc driver for mysql.? There is an Apache derby  jdbc driver that comes with jdk. Make sure you have copied the correct file.

Comment: `lib/ext` is deprecated and will be removed in Java 9, don't put stuff in it, and it is not the same as putting it in the tomcat lib folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You define your datasource in Tomcat's configuration instead of putting it to your application configuration.

Tomcat has hierarchy of classloaders. You can read about it on its [website](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html), but to make the long story short there are three interesting classloaders: a JDK Classloader (Bootstrap), Tomcat classloader (System) and your app's classloader (In fact there are more, but lets make it simple).

When put the driver's jar into $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext/, you add it to JDK classloader. When you add it to tomcat/lib, you add it to Tomcat classloader. And when you define it in your app's gradle, you add it to application classloader.

Since the datasource configuration in your case is located in Tomcat's config, it will search only the JDKs and Tomcat's classloader.

One solution is to define the datasource configuration within your app (why do you need it in Tomcat? Do you have multiple wars that use the same datasource? )

Comment: I have confirmed that there are multiple WARs that use the same datasource. So could I just throw that mysql JAR into all of the other WARs and then take our the datasource definition in Tomcat?

Comment: It depends what you want to achieve. Do you want each WAR to REPLICATE the datasource or you want them to REUSE it?

Comment: If you want to REUSE it, you should leave its configuration in Tomcat's config (as before) and leave the driver in the Tomcat's classloader (tomcat/lib). You cannot put it in application's gradle file.

Comment: I believe we want to reuse it until it is time to move to AWS. Would it make sense to leave the Tomcat config the same and the classloader in tomcat/lib, while keeping the gradle dependency in there?

The gradle dependency will be ignored in our current environments with shared Tomcats, but when we move to the cloud, the gradle dependency would take over.

Comment: It will probably work without an issue, but some theoretical problems can occur. Tomcat works "parent last", it means that when your app is looking for a class, it first checks the app's classloader, then the shared one, and last the bootstrap. Therefore if your app will create class from the driver's jar, it will be different class from the class that is shared (Notice I'm talking about classes here, not about objects).
Since your app doesn't use the classes directly, there will be no issue, but if it start using them, there might be.